# SQL - Selecting most recent rows by timestamp created that correlate to another timestamp column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have this table "forecasts"

```
| id | forecast_timestamp     | created_timestamp             |
| -- | ---------------------- | ----------------------------- |
| 1  | 2021-09-24 09:00:00+00 | 2021-09-23 20:01:03.891939+00 | <-- outdated forecast (it's been re-forecasted by the newer forecast, but I still want to keep it for historical purposes)
| 2  | 2021-09-24 09:00:00+00 | 2021-09-23 23:01:03.964427+00 | <-- newest forecast for 2021-09-24 09:00:00+00
| 3  | 2021-09-24 10:00:00+00 | 2021-09-23 22:43:22.142174+00 | <-- another forecast, but with completely different timestamps - however, it's still the most recent forecast for 2021-09-24 10:00:00+00
```

I want a query that will select the most recent forecasts based on the created_timestamp, and so it should return this:

```
| id | forecast_timestamp     | created_timestamp             |
| -- | ---------------------- | ----------------------------- |
| 2  | 2021-09-24 09:00:00+00 | 2021-09-23 23:01:03.964427+00 |
| 3  | 2021-09-24 10:00:00+00 | 2021-09-23 22:43:22.142174+00 |
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most recent record MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713186/most-recent-record-ms-sql)

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-order-by/

Answer (score 0):

Also see Postgres [Select distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-select.html) clause. ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d218d666d36cd8c130e8b830b83e1401))

```
select distinct on (f.forecast_timestamp)
       f.* 
  from forcast f
 order by forecast_timestamp,created_timestamp desc;
```